# How can I reference full qualified class name in Jenkins Jelly file?

Tags: java, jenkins, jelly

In Jenkins jelly file, I have need to use java class object from class name.

```
<j:set var="myProperty" value="${job.getProperty(MyProperty.class)}" />
```

MyProperty is my custom JobProperty class, which is applied to job
However, the above line will not work properly, even I tried

```
<j:set var="myClass" value="${MyProperty.class}" />
```

or

```
<j:set var="myClass" value="${full.qualified.class.MyProperty.class}" />
```

myClass object will always been null.

How I can use class object from jelly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do something like:

```
<j:set var="myClass" value="$it.class.classLoader.loadClass('full.qualified.class.MyProperty.class')}" />
```

because I found a line similar to this in the JUnit plugin's jobMain.jelly file.

I'm guessing that there's not really a log available from the jelly file except what's handed into it.